# SQL Query not throwing error even if the entered scale value is higher than specified

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis, type-conversion

I need to capture numeric values without truncation. But the output value is getting truncated even though I specified the Scale as '2'.

Column **'A'** datatype - ***numeric(5,2)***

**Case 1:**

**Entered value:** `123.55689335218777665555777778899995544`

**Output :** `123.56`

**Case 2:**

**Entered value:** `1234.55689335218777665555777778899995544`

**Output:** `Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.`

My question is why I am not receiving any error when the scale is higher than '2' but I am getting error when the precision is higher than 3.

I am facing this issue in SSIS Data Conversion task. I need to capture the rows which are truncated in another table. Simplified this question in this way for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 5):

The biggest number you can fit into `numeric(5,2)` is `999.99`. Therefore `123.556...` is fine, but `1234.556...` is too big.

You can find the rules for truncation, rounding, and errors during implicit conversions in the documentation:

- [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms187928.aspx)

I don't know SQL-server that well, so I don’t know if you can configure the behaviour. One idea is to load the data into a table with say *numeric(7,4)*. You can then check which values are truncated by a query similar to:

```
select t1.<key> 
from t1 join t2 
    on t1.<key> = t2.<key> 
where t2.<col> - t1.<col> <> 0
```